# Recordset does not open in VBA Excel

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a problem with Excel VBA recordset, it runs all other queries but this one particular query which runs in SQL Server does not open with the Recordset.
Here is the code chunk:

```
SQL2 = "DECLARE @val VARCHAR (2000) " & vbCrLf & "DECLARE @cert VARCHAR(2000) " & vbCrLf & _
    "DECLARE @inv VARCHAR(2000) " & vbCrLf & "DECLARE @loc INT " & vbCrLf & _
    "DECLARE @res TABLE(val VARCHAR(100)) " & vbCrLf & _
    "DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(2) " & vbCrLf & "SET @val = '' " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET @Delimiter = ',' " & vbCrLf & "SELECT @cert = " & vbCrLf & "CASE WHEN @cert = '' " & vbCrLf & _
    "THEN CertInvsRec " & vbCrLf & "ELSE @cert + coalesce(',' + CertInvsRec, '') " & vbCrLf & _
    "End " & vbCrLf & "FROM  ProjValuations WHERE (Proj = 'TPL-15-020') " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT @inv = " & vbCrLf & "CASE WHEN @inv = '' " & vbCrLf & "THEN InvsAmountRec " & vbCrLf & _
    "ELSE @inv + coalesce(',' + InvsAmountRec, '') " & vbCrLf & "End " & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM  ProjValuations WHERE (Proj = 'TPL-15-020') " & vbCrLf & "SET @val = CONCAT(@inv, ',', @cert) " & vbCrLf & _
    "IF NOT  @val = ',' " & vbCrLf & "DECLARE @Index SMALLINT, @Start SMALLINT, @DelSize SMALLINT " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET @DelSize = LEN(@Delimiter) " & vbCrLf & "WHILE LEN(@val) > 0 " & vbCrLf & "BEGIN " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @val) " & vbCrLf & "IF @Index = 0 " & vbCrLf & "BEGIN " & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT INTO @res(val) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(@val))) " & vbCrLf & "BREAK " & vbCrLf & _
    "End " & vbCrLf & "Else " & vbCrLf & "BEGIN " & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT INTO @res (val) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@val, 1,@Index - 1)))) " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET @val = SUBSTRING(@val, @Start , LEN(@val) - @Start + 1) " & vbCrLf & "End " & vbCrLf & _
    "End " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "SELECT " & vbCrLf & "( " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT sum(InvTotExcl) FROM invnum WHERE autoindex in ( " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT iInvoiceID FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode LIKE '%020%') AND " & vbCrLf & _
    "(StatusDescription = 'CERTIFICATE') and iInvoiceID not in (SELECT * FROM @res)) " & vbCrLf & _
    ") " & vbCrLf & " AS certAmnt, " & vbCrLf & "( " & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT SUM(InvTotExcl) FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode = 'TPL-15-020') AND " & vbCrLf & _
    "(StatusDescription = 'STANDARD') and iInvoiceID not in (SELECT * FROM @res) " & vbCrLf & ") AS invAmnt" 
If rsAmnts.State = adStateOpen Then rsAmnts.Close 
rsAmnts.Open SQL2, CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

If it helps, If I use direct SELECT queries like e.g. **SELECT * FROM things** it runs, could be because of the variable declarations, so maybe should I move the query to a procedure?

Comment: sql server? oracle? please tag the question with the db flavor you are using.

Comment: If you do `debug.print SQL2` in the immediate window and then run the query in SQL does it run ok?

Comment: what is the error number you have? if there is no runtime error then the problem is inside the SQL which is rather ok but not valid for your database/table

Comment: @shahkalpesh its sql server

Comment: @GaryEvans yes it runs okay, just in the code is where it doesn't run

Comment: @KazimierzJawor how can I fetch the error number?

Comment: you can show the other part of your subroutine

Comment: I think you have just answered your question, I was impressed you could pass through variable declarations, assuming `rsAmnts` is a connection try `execute` instead maybe? I.e. `Set Recordset = rsAmnts.Execute(SQL2)`

Comment: @GaryEvans Then how will I access the values, I mean I know Recordset is a class, in short just can you give me from assigning connection object to the recordset to executing it please

Comment: I shifted the whole query to a procedure and its working okay right now, thanx for the help though everyone

Answer (score 1):

So a solution I found that worked is by creating a procedure out of the SQL Query

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[valuationReports]    Script Date: 1/9/2017 17:24:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[valuationReports] 
    @proj AS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @val VARCHAR (2000)
    DECLARE @cert VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @inv VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @loc INT
    DECLARE @res TABLE(val VARCHAR(100))
    DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(2)
    SET @val = ''
    SET @Delimiter = ','
    SELECT @cert = coalesce(',' + CertInvsRec, '')
        FROM  ProjValuations WHERE (Proj = @proj)
    SELECT @inv = coalesce(',' + InvsAmountRec, '')
        FROM  ProjValuations WHERE (Proj = @proj)
    SET @val = CONCAT(@inv, ',', @cert)
    --select @val as 'tst'
    IF NOT  @val = ','
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Index SMALLINT, @Start SMALLINT, @DelSize SMALLINT
        SET @DelSize = LEN(@Delimiter)
        WHILE LEN(@val) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @val)
            IF @Index = 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @res(val) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(@val)))
                    BREAK
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @res (val) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@val, 1,@Index - 1))))
                    SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
                    SET @val = SUBSTRING(@val, @Start , LEN(@val) - @Start + 1)
                END
        END
    END
    SET @cert = ''
    SET @inv = ''
    SELECT @cert = 
        CASE WHEN @cert = ''
        THEN cast(iInvoiceID as varchar)
        ELSE @cert + coalesce(',' + cast(iInvoiceID as varchar), '')
        END
        FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode = @proj) AND 
        (StatusDescription = 'CERTIFICATE') AND iInvoiceID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @res)
    SELECT @inv = 
        CASE WHEN @inv = ''
        THEN cast(iInvoiceID as varchar)
        ELSE @inv + coalesce(',' + cast(iInvoiceID as varchar), '')
        END
        FROM  _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode = @proj) AND 
        (StatusDescription = 'STANDARD') AND iInvoiceID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @res)

    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(InvTotExcl), 0) FROM invnum WHERE autoindex in (
        SELECT iInvoiceID FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode = @proj) AND 
        (StatusDescription = 'CERTIFICATE') AND iInvoiceID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @res)
        )
    ) AS 'cert',
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(InvTotExcl), 0) FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull WHERE (ProjectCode = @proj) AND 
        (StatusDescription = 'STANDARD') AND iInvoiceID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @res)
    ) AS 'inv',
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(@cert, '')
    ) AS 'certIn',
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(@inv, '')
    ) AS 'invIn'

END

GO
```

And the VBA code which I used is

```
'Declare variables
Dim CN As Connection
Dim cmd As Command, rsAmnts As Recordset

'Initialise the variables
Set CN = New Connection
Set cmd = New Command

'Open connection
CN.Open ("connection string")

'Call procedure assigning the variable
cmd.ActiveConnection = CN
cmd.CommandText = "valuationReports"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh

'The variable assigned a value
cmd(1) = "TP-15-0020"

'Set Recordset by executing the command i.e. procedure
Set rsAmnts = cmd.Execute
```

Hope this helps anyone out there

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open the immediate window, paste your code like this and press enter on every line:

[image]

Step 2: Write this and see what you get, when you press ENTER:

[image]

Step 3: Check the result carefully. Try to take it into the SQL Server and to see the error there.

Comment: Did exactly that but it runs perfectly in SQL Server, no errors. in VB.NET just like it does not execute the `rsAmnts.Open SQL2, CN` line because I checked and the recordset is still closed even after execution

Comment: still nothing, trying to shift it to a procedure right now

Comment: I shifted the whole query to a procedure and its working okay now, thanks for the help though

Comment: How did you shift a query to a procedure?

Comment: instead of the raw SQL, I put the whole code in a procedure and now instead of executing the query am just calling the procedure @vityata

Comment: @lulliezy, can you give a link to the procedure. E.g. paste it here - pastebin.com and let me know. I was doing similar stuff before and I was wondering whether I was doing it right.

Comment: [here you go](http://pastebin.com/NRYBkD0L), I hope I did it right (the pasting thing)

Comment: I see. Thanks. But how do call this SQL from VBA?

Comment: The `adCmdStoredProc` is probably the saved query?

Comment: the `adCmdStoredProc` is to instruct the vba command that the query string is actually a stored procedure name, the command text is the name of the procedure

Comment: I see. So you have a stored procedure in the SQL Server `StoredProcedure [dbo].[valuationReports] ` and you have simply called it from VBA. Wise! :) Probably it would be a good idea to write your own answer with these two, it can be useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer but it won't fit in comments and may solve the issue.

You are using `Connection.Open` which according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676505(v=vs.85).aspx) may not get you a recordset right away: -

> Opens a connection to a data source.

And

> When used on a client-side Connection object, the Open method doesn't actually establish a connection to the server until a Recordset is opened on the Connection object.

It could be a case of assigning it to a `Recordset` object exposes it as a recordset.

Whereas with `Connection.Execute`, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023(v=vs.85).aspx) will return a recordset: -

> Returns a Recordset Object (ADO) object reference.

And

> Executes the specified query, SQL statement, stored procedure, or provider-specific text.

What I read from this is that `Connection.Open` will open a connection, this may not be the case of executing specific commands, but simply opening access to data. `Connection.Execute` explicitly mentions running queries and commands, so may accept your declarations as well as standard queries.

Quick example of execute: -

```
Public Sub Sample(ByVal SQL2 As String)
Dim DBConn  As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS      As ADODB.Recordset

Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
    DBConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=[SERVER];Database=[DATABASE];User Id=[USER];Password=[PASSWORD;"
    Set RS = DBConn.Execute(SQL2)
        'RS is a recordset at this point
        RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    DBConn.Close
Set DBConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I shifted the whole query to a procedure and its working okay now, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check regional settings, this will affect how the data is entered into the DB